# Error binding context to html template with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, itext, thymeleaf

I am trying to get some form data into a html template and ultimately to PDF using iText. On the line:

```
String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
```

I get the error:

> 2018-09-12 12:13:17.680 ERROR 18264 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
>   [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template
>   "output.html": An error happened during template parsing (template:
>   "class path resource [templates/output.html]")
>
> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Cannot process attribute
>   '{th:field,data-th-field}': no associated BindStatus could be found
>   for the intended form binding operations. This can be due to the lack
>   of a proper management of the Spring RequestContext, which is usually
>   done through the ThymeleafView or ThymeleafReactiveView (template:
>   "output.html" - line 52, col 36) 
>           at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
>   ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE] 
>           at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE] 
>           at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE] 
>           ... 61 common frames omitted

output.html line 52 is :

```
   <input type="number" class="form-control inputnid person text-uppercase" 
         data-property="nid" id="nid" placeholder="NID" 
         th:field="*{assessment.nid}"/>
```

The full method is:

```
public class PdfGeneratorUtil { 

    public static final String BASEURI = "src/main/resources/static"; 
    @Qualifier("templateEngine") 
    @Autowired 
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine; 

    public void createPdf(String templateName, Map map) throws Exception { 
        Assert.notNull(templateName, "The templateName can not be null"); 
        Context ctx = new Context(); 
        if (map != null) { 
            Iterator itMap = map.entrySet().iterator(); 
            while (itMap.hasNext()) { 
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) itMap.next(); 
                ctx.setVariable(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue()); 
            } 
        } 

        String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx); 
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\tmp\\assessment.pdf"); 
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer); 
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(BASEURI); 
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(processedHtml, pdfDoc, converterProperties); 
        System.out.println("PDF created successfully"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix. As the stack trace hinted at th:field should be th:checked for checkboxes.